# HttpResponse returns null

Tags: android, null, httpresponse

I want to search a diretory with the following php script and get the displayed JSONArray via android app. But everytime I call the android app the HttpResponse null and i dont know why.

PHP:

```
`<?php
$pfad = "./months";
$files = scandir($pfad);
$result = array();
for($a = 2; $a < count($files); $a++)
   {
   $result[] = $files[$a];
   }
print json_encode($result);
?>`
```

If I open the script on my server i get ["5.txt","June2014.txt"].

Android:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    JSONArray finalResult;
    Integer responseCode;
    TextView show;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new MyAsyncTask().execute();

        show = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        show.setText(String.valueOf(responseCode));

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>{

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myurl.php");

            try {
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            return null;

        }


        }

}
```

Note: myurl.php is really the the right server address.

I'd be happy for any help

Comment: Why are you doing a HttpPost and not HttpGet? Are you supposed to send some input as well? I'm not sure if that is the error, but it may be.

Comment: Try to return your response from your `doInBackground` as `return response.toString();`

Comment: HttpGet yields the same result. @GrlsHu: You mean return the response as a String and than display the String? Than i get an empty TextView. I have Internetpermission, do i need any other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're by setting the variable synchronous way to run but the thread is asynchronous then when the TextView variable set not yet have the data then why is giving a NullPointerException.

Change:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

JSONArray finalResult;
TextView show;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new MyAsyncTask().execute();

    show = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    show.setText(String.valueOf(responseCode));

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>{

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myurl.php");

        try {
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;
    }
    }
}
```

to:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

JSONArray finalResult;
Integer responseCode;
TextView show;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    show = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>{

    int responseCode;

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myurl.php");

        try {
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       show.setText(String.valueOf(responseCode));        
    }

    }

   }
```

Comment: I'd have to change onPostExecute(Vodi result) to onPostExecute(Integer resut) in ordner to not get a error Message from Eclipse, but than the app crashes again.

Comment: You do not have to return the result in the doInBackground (Integer resut)you can leave it as I had, pless paste error code.

Comment: I changed the AsyncTask now to <String,Integer,Void> and i get 200 as responseCode :)

Comment: @user3800380 pless check correct answer if I help you.

Answer (score 0):

Put the two code lines after

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute()
```

in onPostExecute() of the async task. You now are too early with them.